# Two CSS Files Defining Same Class - Cross Browser Behavior?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two css files defining same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417287/two-css-files-defining-same-class)

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417287/two-css-files-defining-same-class) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372655/using-two-css-files-in-the-same-html-file) state that when the same selector/property combination is specified in two different CSS files, the one in the file that is included last wins.  My question is, is this behavior part of a standard (HTML or CSS), or is it simply the current behavior in the major browsers?  I need to know if I can depend on this behavior across all browsers.  If this is part of a standard, would you please reference the relevant section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order

The same applies if they are in the same file.

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 25 seconds. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> is this behavior part of a standard (HTML or CSS)

Yes, the [CSS standard defines it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order).

In 6.4.1 Cascading order, bullet point #4:

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.