# How to customize Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization

I want to customize bootstrap using new colors for navs and such. How would I create a separate css file that overrides some of the things on bootstrap.css? (I don't want to mess with the bootstrap css files, incase there are updates to bootstrap, and I don't have to re-add anything).

How do I change the color of the navbar in my custom CSS file?

Comment: Google for it, or even search on SOF, this question has been asked many times

Comment: See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372655/using-two-css-files-in-the-same-html-file

Answer (score 2):

You can add the custom stylesheet after include bootstrap:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="mySpecial.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then, you override the styles you want. So will be something like:

```
.btn-success {
  color: orange;
}
```

for an ugly orange text green button.

Comment: Thanks, but what would I put in the css to change the color of the navbar in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: How would I change the color of the navbar? (I'm using Bootstrap 3)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new stylesheet, link to that below the bootstrap stylesheet then you can use the same CSS rules and your new stylesheet will over-ride bootstrap because it is linked to afterwards.

Comment: Other answer is better

Comment: How would I change the color of the navbar? (I'm using Bootstrap 3)